# Algorithm to perform K-combinations for all k on sentences

Tags: python, bash, combinations

I have a file: `test.txt` with a sentence on each line.

```
Hello World  
99 Bottles of Beer  
Humpty Dumpty Sat on the wall
```

I wish to produce an output displaying all combinations of the input from this file (i.e. 2<sup>n</sup>-1 combinations). In the above instance, the algorithm will spill out the following - Each combination to be separated with a pipe (`|`)

```
Hello World  
99 Bottles of Beer  
Humpty Dumpty Sat on the wall  
Hello World | 99 Bottles of Beer  
Hello World | Humpty Dumpty Sat on the wall  
99 Bottles of Beer | Humpty Dumpty Sat on the wall  
Hello World | 99 Bottles of Beer | Humpty Dumpty Sat on the wall
```

Ideally, I would like this to be done in bash or python or perl scripting but I am open to suggestions.

Comment: have you given a shot and failed? If yes, what was that?

Comment: Isn't it (2^n)-1 ? And isn't an output with no strings valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import itertools

l = [s.strip() for s in open('test.txt')]

for i in range(len(l)):
  print '\n'.join(map(' | '.join, itertools.combinations(l, i + 1)))
```

produces

```
Hello World
99 Bottles of Beer
Humpty Dumpty Sat on the wall
Hello World | 99 Bottles of Beer
Hello World | Humpty Dumpty Sat on the wall
99 Bottles of Beer | Humpty Dumpty Sat on the wall
Hello World | 99 Bottles of Beer | Humpty Dumpty Sat on the wall
```

If you don't like the style of `'\n'.join()` (I am not sure I do), you could replace it with an explicit loop:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
  for c in map(' | '.join, itertools.combinations(l, i + 1)):
    print c
```

This is slightly more verbose, but is more economical.

Comment: Oh wait, I forgot i could use combinations. *bangs head on wall*.

Comment: Thanks guys! I spent last 1 hr trying to do this using for loops and still couldn't produce the output that I was after. _Bows down to the power of python's itertools_

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
import itertools

file = open("test.txt")
lines = files.readlines()

current = []
for i in range(len(lines):
    current.append(i)

    for combination in set(itertools.permutations(current)):
        for l in combination:
            output+=' | '.join(lines[l])
        output+= '\n'
print output
```

I'm weary about my itertools & set skills, but this should work, unless there are memory constraints..